# I am trying to call the signOut() function for the Google Sign-in api but keep getting the error "gapi is not defined"

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am trying to call the `SignOut()` function for Google sign-in on my website. I have got the sign in process working, I am just having trouble with the sign out process.

I found the sign out function here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user

The function looks like this:

```
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
```

I have this function in a file called entire-site.js which I load into the HTML. Here are the scripts I am using

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/entire-site.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

The sign out button looks like this:

```
<button class="displayNone" id="signOutButton" onclick="signOutButton()">Sign Out</button>
```

That calls a function called `signOutButton()`. Inside of `signOutButton()` the `signOut()` is called. I call it inside of `signOutButton()` as I also need to open a connection with my server and do other things there.

Whenever I click the sign out button, it gets stuck in the signOut() function, saying that "gapi is not defined"

What I've tried:

There are some similar questions on stack overflow but I couldn't manage to figure it out. I know it's something to do with that gapi hasn't been loaded yet as in the script its `async defer`, I tried some stuff from their answers.

I tried using `gapi.load('auth2', signOut);`

I made `auth2` a global variable.

Inside my `signOutButton()`

```
function signOutButton(){

    //log them out in google
    auth2 = gapi.load('auth2', signOut);
    SignOut();
        .
        .
        .
}
```

I still got that "gapi is not defined"

Thanks

Comment: Do you loading scripts inside <head> ? Try to create your function inside $("document").ready() , or javascript alternative if you are using pure javascript.

Comment: Yeah all my scripts are loaded in the ```<head>```. I am not really sure what ```$("document").ready() ``` is?

Comment: $("document").ready(function(){ //functions and variables }) means, that all your functions and variable created after page is loaded, not sure if you can do workaround by assigning "onclick" event as button property. As code that you show to us looks fine, I think something is not loaded at right time. By the way does console show any other error? You may want to activate "preserve log" function to all logs from page start.

Comment: May be you can put your whole html as is, then we can try to repeat your error and search for fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out when I was trying to sign out, I was on a different page where the google api scripts had not loaded. I needed to go to the page where you log out and add the appropriate script tags.

My university tutor helped me, there was another error after gapi had been defined, I didn't see it as he fixed it pretty quick. In the end I now have the following code in the `<head>` tags.

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">

    <script>
        function onLoad() {
            gapi.load('auth2', function() {
                gapi.auth2.init();
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>
```

Replace `MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` with your own.